# Use regular expression to match a string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I used a following regular expression to find some strings in different files opened using Notepad++.But getting error box saying invalid regular expression

```
<Variable Id="File" Value=(*)/>
```

The possible values that iam trying to match are.

```
 <Variable Id="File" Value="null"/>
 <Variable Id="File" Value="autorun.ini"/>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added a `.`

Use this regex:

```
<Variable Id="File" Value=(.*)/>
```

`.*` means match all character

Comment: @user1654136, mark it as answer mate, since it helped. Also upvote ;)

Comment: Sure Amit,i did,
is there any way to omit the blank line if i remove an entire line using the above regular expression

Comment: yes i Upvoted,but can't able to accept.It says wait for 5 minutes

Comment: Yes there is a time limit. But you can do after 5 minutes